# Reading files list for package 'linux-headers-3.19.0-80-generic': Input/output error

Tags: kernel

i tried to update Firefox by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

but it got stucked at 95% and gave an error

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'linux-headers-3.19.0-80-generic': Input/output error
Error in function:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disk error? Disk full? `df`

Comment: For 'Input/output' errors, an early step is to look up how to run a SMART test on the drive. Rule out hardware problems - Ubuntu is not designed to run on defective or dying hardware.

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 2 years.